# How to reduce all whitespace in a string to single spaces?

Tags: string, vb6, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

Using VB6 *without* any additional references such as Regex, how can I convert a string so that all whitespace in a string is reduced to single spaces?

eg.

```
" A    B C D   E"
```

would be converted to

```
"A B C D E"
```

Comment: It's hard to see what you mean from the example; I assume you want to eliminate all consecutive strings of whitespace to a single whitespace per occurrence?  So for instance, if we let . be a whitespace (so we could see it) then A..B....C.D..E would become A.B.C.D.E?

Comment: That's correct. Jason has edited it correctly for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function NormalizeSpaces(s As String) As String

    Do While InStr(s, String(2, " ")) > 0
        s = replace(s, String(2, " "), " ")
    Loop
    NormalizeSpaces = s

End Function
```

(derived from: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/normalizing-spaces-in-vb6-strings/5890164)

Comment: This will work quickly, but I think it's a little neater to use "  " instead of String(2, " "). Just my $.02

Comment: +1 @Tom Collins I think `Space(2)` is more readable still! The [Space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263361(v=vs.60).aspx) function returns a String containing the specified number of spaces.

Comment: Do you have a VBA version of this please?